# Updating Ant on mac

Tags: macos, ant, build.xml

I am running ant 1.8.2 and I want to up date to the latest on my mac. What is the best way to do this? Should I remove then install or can i write over the previous?

I use it in both Eclipse and from the command line. I also have jenkins call ant targets. It's currently set in /usr/local

Answer (score 6):

I found these two links to update Ant on mac:

[Seventy6.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20140707022532/http://seventy6.com/post/14175174562/how-to-upgrade-apache-ant-to-1-8-2-on-osx-using)
[Ninjascript.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20150313163749/http://www.blog.ninjascript.com/2011/02/ant-ftp-task-on-os-x/)

I had Ant 1.8.4 installed on my Mac 10.8.5 and upgraded to:

```
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.4 compiled on April 29 2014
```

The first website from seventy6 said all of the below, with a few updates from myself.

---

To see what version you currently have installed run this:

```
$ ant -version
Apache Ant version 1.7.1 compiled on February 11 2010
```

I was advised to use the simple OSX package installer [homebrew](http://brew.sh/). I’m not going to discuss how to install this, as they have a [really simple guide](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/installation). However, it’s not obvious how to install Apache Ant as it’s not one of the packages they list. So here is the brew to get started:

```
$brew install https://raw.github.com/adamv/homebrew-alt/master/duplicates/ant.rb
```

**EDIT: You can also just install now with homebrew just by typing the following**

```
$brew install ant
```

Beware, you might need to install Apple’s [XCode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/), which if you’re still running OS X 10.6 or lower (like me) you can’t install the latest version (4) via the wonderful (?) AppStore. Ha! fun and games! Luckily, I have an Apple Developer account which allows you to download archived releases of Apple’s software. I created this ages ago and assume they’re still free to do… Once installed it puts the package here:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.8.2
```

I then scratched my head for a while as to how to get OSX to use the newly installed version. It seems the easiest option is to remove the symlink currently set for the system. Run this to see where this is:

```
$ whereis ant
/usr/bin/ant       //returned message
```

So we need to remove the symlink and set it to our new installed copy. I found this article which got me started. Useful, but not perfect for a homebrew package install. So here is the final commands to change the symlink to the homebrew version:

```
$ cd /usr/share
$ sudo rm /usr/share/ant
Password:
************
$ ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.8.2 ant
```

You now need to close your current terminal session and open a new one. In theory you should be able to run 'ant -version' to get the latest version…

```
$ ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
```

I’m not sure if it’s best way to do it. But it’s a simple technique which can easily be updated if needed. At least you haven’t removed the base Java install of Ant from your system!

## DONE

Also from blog.ninjascript.com, I saw this was interesting to know about:

Now Ant is kind of buried in OS X; the $PATH variable points to a symlink which points to another symlink. To find out where ant really is, just follow the chain:

```
$ which ant
/usr/bin/ant
$ ls -la /usr/bin/ant
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  22 Nov 11 18:04 /usr/bin/ant -> /usr/share/ant/bin/ant
$ ls -la /usr/share/ant
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  14 Nov 11 18:04 /usr/share/ant -> java/ant-1.7.1
$ ls -la /usr/share/java/ant-1.7.1
total 40
drwxr-xr-x   8 root  wheel    272 Feb 27 12:32 .
drwxr-xr-x   8 root  wheel    272 Nov 11 18:04 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel  15289 Feb 10  2010 LICENSE.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel   1270 Feb 10  2010 NOTICE.txt
drwxr-xr-x   8 root  wheel    272 Feb 10  2010 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel    102 Feb 10  2010 docs
drwxr-xr-x  15 root  wheel    510 Feb 10  2010 etc
drwxr-xr-x  44 root  wheel   1496 Feb 27 12:09 lib
```

Comment: brew install ant is awesome for => Mac OSX 10.*.*

Comment: $brew install https://raw.github.com/adamv/homebrew-alt/master/duplicates/ant.rb seems to be unaviable

Comment: and http://seventy6.com/post/14175174562/how-to-upgrade-apache-ant-to-1-8-2-on-osx-using